# Get control which is inside SideBarTemplate of wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net wizard control, I have a datalist inside its SideBarTemplate, I have a button on Wizard control, I want to access the datalist on button click
 This is my Wizard Control

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick"
            FinishCompleteButtonText="Submit" OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick"
            OnPreviousButtonClick="Wizard1_PreviousButtonClick" StepStyle-CssClass="WizardRightPart"
            CssClass="WizardContainer" ActiveStepIndex="0">
            <SideBarStyle CssClass="WizardLeftPart" Height="620" />

  <StartNavigationTemplate>
                <table class="WizardButtonRow" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveExit" runat="server" SkinID="ANHButton2" Text="Save & Exit"
                                CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnSaveExit_Click" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </StartNavigationTemplate>

<SideBarTemplate>
    <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="SideBarList" OnItemDataBound="SideBarList1_ItemDataBound"
                    SelectedItemStyle-Width="100%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SideBarButton" class="SideBarLinkItem" CausesValidation="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
</SideBarTemplate>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

I have tried this

```
Wizard1.FindControl("SideBarTemplate")
```

It is accessing it sidebartemplate,But it has no method for FindControl
Also tried this but its appearing null

```
Wizard1.FindControl("SideBarTemplate$SideBarList")
```

I have also tried this but still its null

```
Page.FindControl("Wizard1$SideBarTemplate$SideBarList")
```

Comment: Try `Wizard1.FindControl("SideBarContainer")` as this blog says to use `HeaderContainer` for `HeaderTemplate`. http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/PostId/461/Wizard-Control-Programmatically-Access-the-Header

Answer (score 1):

```
Table wizardTable = Wizard1.ActiveStep.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as Table;
DataList sideBarList = wizardTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("SideBarList") as DataList;
```

Yes `Wizard` control is nasty.